# Maximum value of ActiveResource timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timeout, activeresource

This is a bad thing to do but this temporary fix I want to push to production wants me to increase the timeout of `ActiveResource`. I've set it to 120 seconds. 
How much further can it go ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could push it as far as you want. At some point the client's browser will timeout itself and leave your user with an error.

One of the points of the timeout value is to stop trying when it's going to fail. If you set it to high, there is no point in using one.